# asp.net mvc model the same as (database mapped) object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have the following setup: fluent nhibernate + asp.net mvc 4. 
I have a seperate project in VS where all my objects are stored, these objects are directly mapped to the database.

However, to display data from these objects in the views, I need 'models'.

Do I need to create new model objects, based on these database mapped objects, or can I just pass these database objects as a model to the view? (is this a good idea?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should create additional ViewModel classes. If some changes are to be made to the data that get displayed, it's easier to just modify these models; your domain mappings will not be affected by some particular "rendering" circumstances.

Another advantage would be that you can decorate the properties with formating attributes, without enforcing these settings on future projects that depend on your domain.

For example, say you have the following `Customer` class in your base project:

```
public class Customer
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

You can add a `[Required]` attribute on the `Name` property to make it mandatory. If for a particular project you need to also make the `Address` property mandatory, you would decorate it with another `[Required]` attribute. If you directly use the domain model classes, you will enforce that the `Address` property would always be required, even though the project requirements would not state that. This can be further extended to different validation attributes and also additional data that you may want to sent to the view along with the model (such as composite fields).

Comment: I was thinking about a future need where there are differences between what I want to show on the page VS the object as it is mapped to the database. I think I go for (mirror) seperate model objects :)

Answer (score 0):

This is largely a design decision that depends on the size of the project, etc.  Without getting into too much detail, the short answer is yes, you can use your database objects/models directly in your Views.

Sometimes it may be desirable to create specific view models if you only want to show a subset of the fields, or do different validation than the database in your View. You can then can validate this view model in your controller and if everything is okay, map it to your nHibernate models.